# Full Text Search generates wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am using FULLTEXT search in two different tables in single query. Which generates wrong result.

```
select c.*, s.s_name, s.logo, s.s_slug, cm.coupon_code, cm.c_shorturl, cm.c_shorturl_id 
from ci_coupons c 
left join ci_stores s on s.store_id = c.store_id 
left join ci_coupons_mapper cm on cm.coupon_id = c.coupon_id 
where c.c_link_type like "%Banner%" 
      and c.c_width='300' 
      and match(c.c_name) against('+trend +micro') or match(s.display_name) against('+trend +micro')  

order by c.coupon_id desc
```

In the above query, i am searching `+trend +micro` in `c.c_name` and `s.display_name` fields but i want the result with `c_link_type` has `Banner`. But i get this result

[image]

That has `c_link_type` blank which is wrong, and that is because of FULLTEXT, Can anyone guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best guess I can see with the data provided in your screenshot, you are missing parens around:

```
and (match(c.c_name) against('+trend +micro') or match(s.display_name) against('+trend +micro'))
```

I bet your s.display_name column has 'Trend Micro' in it.